# Problem with Filldown and Replace and Formula

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$1023").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    "cancelled"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$1023").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="1"


Cells.Find(What:="cancelled", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 3) = "later"
Cells.Find(What:="cancelled", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 3).Select

Selection.FillDown
```

Those are my code. Then I copy pasted it to another worksheet, and the change to "later" disappeared

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: For the first part you, can simply do `Cells.Find(What:="cancelled", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0,3).value = "later"` There is no need for all this Activating and Selecting. `Activate` and `Select` are things that a human does, but VBA doesn't have to bother. I can't say why your "FillDown" isn't working.

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited as you suggested, now there is mistake with FIlldown.

Comment: Perhaps, since `filldown` is needed here you can first set a variable as a "range" type to hold the cell that is found by the `Find` method. Then set it's value, then `filldown` from there. So 1 line: `Dim foundCell as Range`; 2nd line: `Set foundCell = .Find(What:="cancelled", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0,3)`; 3rd line; `foundCell.Value = "later"` then you can do your filldown like `foundCell.FillDown`

Comment: What I wanted to filldown is from the cell that has been changed to Later. I now followed your suggestion JNevill, but "later" is no longer there. What I did after doing with the above code is to copy and paste it to another worksheet. Perhaps that is why "later" disappeared?

Comment: @FARRAF maybe try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823774/11167163) , Is it the result excepted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that  `.FillDown` Work with a **range of cells** and not a single cells.

This should work

```
Sub test()

Dim Foundcell As Range

Set Foundcell = Cells.Find(What:="cancelled", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 3)

Foundcell.Value = "later"


Range(Foundcell.Address, "D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

End Sub
```

Output (does this match to your needs) :

[image]

For the code you just added It is better to **avoid** `select`

Hope this helps, Waiting for your feedbacks

Comment: @FARRAF Glad I could help you, may I ask you to **accept** this answer?

Comment: @FARRAF Accept this answer will set this issue as **SOLVED** So it helps others which are stuck with .FillDown [Click here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) Kindest regards